# Use CSOM To Pull Date Value From Date And Time Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, development, csom

Using C# CSOM and this is SharePoint 2010 - I am attempting to pull the vale of a Date And a time field to my Winform.

If I type in the immediate window
    listItem[“datetimefield”];

It will return
    {7/22/2018 3:22:00 AM}
    Date:
    Day:
    DayOfWeek:
    DayOfYear:
    Hour:
    Kind:
    Millisecond:
    Minute:
    Month:
    Seconds:
    Ticks:
    TimeOfDay:
    Year:

I want to pull the value from Date - what would be the syntax to do such?

**EDIT**
If it helps this is full syntax I attempted to use.  I can connect fine and pull values for other field types, just not a Date and Time field type.

```
Public static void GetDateTimeData()
{
  using (var ctx = new ClientContext(SPURL))
  {
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(SPSite);
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml= strong.Format();

    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.Load(list);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
    {
        DateTime TargetSD = (dateTime)listItem["maindate"];
        string date = Convert.ToDateTime(listItem["maindate"].ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just stick it in a DateTime variable

Comment: I tried and I was obviously doing it incorrectly as it would just launch my winform. I will show code I try when I get back to my PC

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint 2013 environment, if I get the value from the date and time column in the item, I get the time as the picture below.

[image]

Then you could format the time according to the article below.

[String Format for DateTime.](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: -> what syntax did you use to pull the date?  I tried to use `DateTime TargetSD = (dateTime)listItem["maindate"];
string date = Convert.ToDateTime(listItem["maindate"].ToString();`  but the code above for me and SharePoint 2010 does not actually provide me with the value from the Date and Time field.  And yes, I did verify that there actually is a date in the field.

Comment: I just use the code “Console.WriteLine(item["date1"]);”.

Answer (score 0):

The value is already `DateTime`. If that's what you want, `casting` will be enough:

```
(DateTime)listItem["maindate"]
```

But if you need as a formatted string, use the `toString()` method:

```
DateTime dateTimeValue = (DateTime)listItem["maindate"];
string formatedValue = dateTimeValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You may look here if you want to customize the format:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings